# Shuffle letters in one cell

Tags: regex, string, random, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I would like to shuffle the letters in a Google Sheets cell. So if A1 contains `hello` a result like `leloh`.

How to do this?

Comment: How do you think it should be done?  Do you want more characters in the result?  Do you want less characters in the result?  If not, then you might want to count the number of characters to begin with.  You can use JavaScript `length` property of a string to do that.  You'll probably need a loop.  Do you know what a JavaScript `for` loop is?  If not maybe you could do some research.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest first splitting the string by letters:

`=TRANSPOSE(REGEXEXTRACT(A1,rept("(.)",LEN(A1))))`

Then get random numbers for each letter:

`=ARRAYFORMULA(RANDBETWEEN(ROW(INDIRECT("A1:A"&LEN(A1)))^0,50‌​0))`

Then sort and join the result:

`=JOIN(,QUERY(SORT({TRANSPOSE(REGEXEXTRACT(A1,rept("(.)",LEN(A1)))),ARRAYFORMULA(RANDBETWEEN(ROW(INDIRECT("a1:a"&LEN(A1)))^0,500))},2,),
"select Col1"))`

The result is shuffled randomly letters

[image]

---

And this formula will reverse the string:

`=JOIN(,QUERY(SORT({TRANSPOSE(REGEXEXTRACT(A1,rept("(.)",LEN(A1)))),ARRAYFORMULA(ROW(INDIRECT("a1:a"&LEN(A1))))},2,),"select Col1"))`

The result:

`olleh`